# Connectorx giving error to fetch data from database that allows zero dates

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am using connectorx library to load data from MySQL database. The database allows zero date values for datetime columns. So my columns have values like '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and dtype in SQL table is datetime. Fetching data using pandas doesn't give an error but using connectorx it gives the following error. Any suggestions to resolve it?

```
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16620\2207944772.py in <module>
     11 db_url="mysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:{port}/{db}".format(user="cookie",pw="cookie123",db="mydb",port=3306)
     12 query='Select * from reports_after_20230101 limit 20'
---> 13 iris=cx.read_sql(db_url,query)

c:\Users\cbhattac\Anaconda3\envs\cookie\lib\site-packages\connectorx\__init__.py in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
    222             raise ValueError("You need to install pandas first")
    223 
--> 224         result = _read_sql(
    225             conn,
    226             "pandas",

PanicException: Could not retrieve core::option::Option<chrono::naive::datetime::NaiveDateTime> from Value
```