# How can I connect to SQL Server in Python using Polars or ConnectorX without receiving a runtime error?

Tags: sql-server, python-polars

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using either polars or connectorx and I always get a

> RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8

My code is along these lines

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import connectorx as cx

user='my_user'
password='my_password'
server='my_server'
database='my_database'

conn =f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{server}/{database}"

query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[my_table]"
```

When using trying with cx:

```
df = cx.read_sql(conn,query)
```

I get the error:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [4], in ()
> ----> 1 df = cx.read_sql(conn,query)

> File c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\connectorx_*init*_.py:224, in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
> 221 except ModuleNotFoundError:
> 222     raise ValueError("You need to install pandas first")
> --> 224 result = _read_sql(
> 225     conn,
> 226     "pandas",
> 227     queries=queries,
> 228     protocol=protocol,
> 229     partition_query=partition_query,
> 230 )
> 231 df = reconstruct_pandas(result)
> 233 if index_col is not None:

> RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8

If instead I use

```
df = pl.read_sql(query,conn)
```

I get

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in ()
----> 1 df = pl.read_sql(query,conn)

File c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\io\database.py:196, in read_sql(query, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol, engine)
    121 """
    122 Read a SQL query into a DataFrame.
    123 
   (...)
    188 
    189 """
    190 warnings.warn(
    191     "`read_sql` has been renamed; this"
    192     " redirect is temporary, please use `read_database` instead",
    193     category=DeprecationWarning,
    194     stacklevel=find_stacklevel(),
    195 )
--> 196 return read_database(
    197     query=query,
    198     connection_uri=connection_uri,
    199     partition_on=partition_on,
    200     partition_range=partition_range,
    201     partition_num=partition_num,
    202     protocol=protocol,
    203     engine=engine,
    204 )

File c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\io\database.py:95, in read_database(query, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol, engine)
     24 """
     25 Read a SQL query into a DataFrame.
     26 
   (...)
     92 
     93 """
     94 if engine == "connectorx":
---> 95     return _read_sql_connectorx(
     96         query,
     97         connection_uri,
     98         partition_on=partition_on,
     99         partition_range=partition_range,
    100         partition_num=partition_num,
    101         protocol=protocol,
    102     )
    103 elif engine == "adbc":
    104     if not isinstance(query, str):

File c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\io\database.py:222, in _read_sql_connectorx(query, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol)
    217 except ImportError:
    218     raise ImportError(
    219         "connectorx is not installed. Please run `pip install connectorx>=0.3.1`."
    220     ) from None
--> 222 tbl = cx.read_sql(
    223     conn=connection_uri,
    224     query=query,
    225     return_type="arrow2",
    226     partition_on=partition_on,
    227     partition_range=partition_range,
    228     partition_num=partition_num,
    229     protocol=protocol,
    230 )
    232 return from_arrow(tbl)

File c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\connectorx\__init__.py:257, in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
    254 except ModuleNotFoundError:
    255     raise ValueError("You need to install pyarrow first")
--> 257 result = _read_sql(
    258     conn,
    259     "arrow" if return_type in {"arrow", "polars"} else "arrow2",
    260     queries=queries,
    261     protocol=protocol,
    262     partition_query=partition_query,
    263 )
    264 df = reconstruct_arrow(result)
    265 if return_type in {"polars", "polars2"}:

RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8
```

I'd like to get the dataframe directly into polars without having to use `pl.from_pandas()` method.

Any advice?

Comment: `RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8` is usually the last in a series of error text. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76309539/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s). It wouldn't hurt to include the minimal code that reproduces the problem, either, including import statements.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited with more context

Comment: did you see "ModuleNotFoundError: 222 raise ValueError("**You need to install pandas first**")"?

Comment: yes, that makes no sense to me. I use pandas everyday and would like to explore polars.

Comment: related :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75950257/connectorx-giving-error-to-fetch-data-from-database-that-allows-zero-dates

Comment: Do you normally use Python 3.9? Do you normally install packages into `c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages`? How are you executing this script? Seems like it could be the difference between using virtual environments, user profiles and perhaps executing from an SQL Agent job where no user profiles are loaded.

Comment: I posted the answer below, thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, unlike pandas/sqlalchemy, I need to give the connection string directly, not an engine;

```
import polars as pl


user='my_user'
password='my_password'
server='my_server'
database='my_database'

conn_str =f"mssql://{user}:{password}@{server}/{database}?encrypt=true"

query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[my_table]"
df = pl.read_database(query=sql_text, connection_uri=conn_str)
```

If I want to combine sqlalchemy to polars in order to bind variables to my query, then I also need  the query to be a string. I added the workaround below (compiled_query), unless someone know a better way with connectorx

```
import polars as pl
import sqlalchemy
conn_str = f"mssql://{user}:{password}@{server}/{database}?encrypt=true"
sql_text = sqlalchemy.text(
""" 
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Date) AS [Date]
, Exchange_Rate / 100 AS [Exchange_Rate] FROM [dbo].[my_table] WHERE Date >= :Date 
"""
).bindparams(sqlalchemy.bindparam("Date", value="2022-05-31"))
compiled_query = str(sql_text.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})) 
df = pl.read_database(compiled_query, conn_str)
```